# Transfer money without data races

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Problem: Alice (Person's instance) wants to transfer $20 to Bob (Person's instance).

Tables:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Collection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Money { get; set; }

    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Current accounts:

> Alice: $30
>
> Bob: 0$

The service checks if Alice has sufficient money, and then do the transference. But **the problem happens** when a second transference occurs at the same time, wanting to transfer $20 too (double click in the "transfer" button, for example).

The code is the next:

```
int aliceId = 1;
int bobId = 2;
bool sufficientMoney = Accounts.Any(x => x.PersonId == aliceId && x.Money >= 20);

if (sufficientMoney)
{
    Person aliceAccount = Accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PersonId == aliceId);

    Person bobAccount = Accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PersonId == aliceId);

    using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        aliceAccount.Money -= 20;
        bobAccount.Money += 20;

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

It can occur the two readings from the database return Alice has sufficient money, the first request do the valid transference, and the second executes afterwards, having Alice a negative (invalid) amount of money left, and Bob getting money which does not exist.

Comment: I'd handle the sufficientMoney part on the database side with a serializable isolation level. i.e. a procedure which takes the sender, receiver and does this logic check on the DB side.

Comment: This is where Event Sourcing comes in play! Suggest you take a look into that.

Comment: This is because you are processing the actual transfer away from the check for valid balance. Create a procedure that will receive the data for the transfer. In that procedure you check the balance and move the money in a single statement, or at least in a single transaction.

Comment: How so John? @SeanLange suggest the same thing. You can hold explicit locks until the transaction is complete to prevent this type of dirty data.

Comment: @penleychan I can substract $20 and send a message to the service bus, but the error before send the message can occur.

Comment: Not sure if I follow what you said, each event have a version, if you try to write another event with the same version you wouldn't be able to. If this was an enterprise application for banking I would use event sourcing. Otherwise I'd do what other mention.

Comment: @scsimon Ok, sorry. It seems that can be the solution

Comment: And why does your front end allow for double clicks? You should disable it when it gets click to help avoid such ugly things.

Comment: @penleychan If the user call directly to the Payment microservice with RESTful, how should I use the service bus then?

Comment: @scsimon - I'm not sure the big hammer of serializable isolation is required here; repeatable read should be sufficient. A slightly smaller hammer, but smaller nonetheless.

Comment: maybe you can separate logic? for example: every request has its own Id. every request puts in queue on service-side. service has worker, that takes items from queue and processes them sequentially.

Comment: @SeanLange - preventing double clicks would prevent *this instance* of the application from initiating two transfers simultaneously (assuming you can sensibly disable clicks, i.e. that it's not actually asp.net). You still need protection at the database side.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever of course you still database protection but a little front work goes a long way. ;)